# How to display button when all input field has some value using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need one help.I need to display my button while all input has some value using Angular.js.Let me to explain my code below.

```
 <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Product Name :</span>
    <select class="form-control"  id="pro_name" ng-model="pro_name"  ng-change="removeBorder('pro_name');" ng-readonly="periodread" >
<option value="">Select Product</option>
<option value="1">Britania</option>
<option value="0">Soap/option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Unit Cost Price :</span>
    <input type="text" name="discount" id="ucp" class="form-control" placeholder="Add unit cost price" ng-model="unit_cost_price" ng-keypress="clearField('ucp');" ng-readonly="isChecked=='false'">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Unit Sale Price :</span>
    <input type="text" name="discount" id="usp" class="form-control" placeholder="Add unit sale price" ng-model="unit_sale_price" ng-keypress="clearField('usp');" ng-readonly="isChecked=='false'">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Quantity :</span>
    <input type="text" name="discount" id="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Add quantity" ng-model="quantity" ng-keypress="clearField('quantity');">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" ng-show="displayRadio">
    <input type="radio" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="isChecked" value="true">Add new stock
    <input type="radio" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="isChecked" value="false">Update stock 
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addProductstockData(billdata);"  id="addProfileData" ng-value="buttonName" ng-show="showAddButton"/>
```

In the code i need when all field has some value the button will display to user.User can also type/select the value in input field and for some cases values are also appending inside input field bu another button click.So here i need when user has any value inside the input fields then only button will display to user.Please help me.

Comment: you should keep all your feilds inside a form and the show your button once your form is valid.

Comment: From viewing @Saeed answer below. I want to add a UI perspective; I would have the button slightly grayed out and make the click disabled and prompt them to fill fields if they try to click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Here`s the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kwjU5IjarHqKdLeKvE3R?p=preview)! of your code.

All you need to do is wrap up the inputs in the `<form name="theForm" novalidate></form>` and give `required` attribute to inputs and show the button only once the required fields has some value in it, like `<button ng-show="theForm.$valid"></button>`. Hope that helps

Comment: @ Saeed : Still selection field is blank and button is coming.

Comment: Yes, thats right, but that's because you didn't provide any js file or data that you had in your js file, but once you have that, you can put the same `required` attribute to that select tag. Cheers

Comment: But we can test here taking any static data..right?

Comment: if u can just paste the listOfProduct data here I could`ve help out. Sorry for the plunker though, I just changed the plunker that was made by a different person, was too lazy to create a new one.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/kwjU5IjarHqKdLeKvE3R?p=preview      so here is the updated plunker. If you want the select tag to be required, I don't think it's possible to use plain html for that, u need define your options in your js. Check out the plunker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99373/discussion-between-satya-and-saeed-arislan).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('form-example', []);

app.directive('passwordValidate', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {

                scope.pwdValidLength = (viewValue && viewValue.length >= 8 ? 'valid' : undefined);
                scope.pwdHasLetter = (viewValue && /[A-z]/.test(viewValue)) ? 'valid' : undefined;
                scope.pwdHasNumber = (viewValue && /\d/.test(viewValue)) ? 'valid' : undefined;

                if(scope.pwdValidLength && scope.pwdHasLetter && scope.pwdHasNumber) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pwd', true);
                    return viewValue;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('pwd', false);                    
                    return undefined;
                }

            });
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.input-help {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: -6px;
  left: 160px;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#fefefe;
  font-size:.875em;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:0 1px 3px #aaa;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.input-help::before {
  content: "\25C0";
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:-12px;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  color:#ddd;
  text-shadow:none;
}
.input-help h4 {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

/* Always hide the input help when it's pristine */
input.ng-pristine + .input-help {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide the invalid box while the input has focus */
.ng-invalid:focus + .input-help {
  display: none;
}

/* Show a blue border while an input has focus, make sure it overrides everything else */
/* Overriding Twitter Bootstrap cuz I don't agree we need to alarm the user while they're typing */
input:focus {
  color: black !important;
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8) !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6) !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6) !important;
}


/* Show green border when stuff has been typed in, and its valid */
.ng-dirty.ng-valid {
  border-color:#3a7d34;
}

/* Show red border when stuff has been typed in, but its invalid */
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  border-color:#ec3f41;
}

/* Show the help box once it has focus */
.immediate-help:focus + .input-help {
  display: block;
}

/* Immediate help should be red when pristine */
.immediate-help.ng-pristine:focus + .input-help {
  border-color:#ec3f41;
}
.immediate-help.ng-pristine:focus + .input-help::before {
  color:#ec3f41;
}

/* Help hould be green when input is valid */
.ng-valid + .input-help {
  border-color:#3a7d34;
}
.ng-valid + .input-help::before {
  color:#3a7d34;
}

/* Help should show and be red when invalid */
.ng-invalid + .input-help {
  display: block;
  border-color: #ec3f41;
}
.ng-invalid + .input-help::before {
  color: #ec3f41;
}

/* Style input help requirement bullets */
.input-help ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

/* Default each bullet to be invalid with a red cross and text */
.input-help li {
  padding-left: 22px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color:#ec3f41;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat  2px -34px;
}

/* Set to green check and text when valid */
.input-help li.valid {
  color:#3a7d34;
  background-position: 2px 6px;
}

/* Set submit button */
form .btn, form.ng-valid .btn[disabled] {
  display: none;
}
form.ng-invalid .btn[disabled], form.ng-valid .btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
 padding: 20px 0;   
}
input {
    width: 166px
}
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    width: 100px;
}
.form-horizontal .controls {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-app="form-example" class="row form-horizontal" novalidate>
 <div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" required>
    <div class="input-help">
      <h4>Invalid Email</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input ng-model="password" class="immediate-help" password-validate required type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <div class="input-help">
      <h4>Password must meet the following requirements:</h4>
      <ul>
        <li ng-class="pwdHasLetter">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
        <li ng-class="pwdHasNumber">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
        <li ng-class="pwdValidLength">At least <strong>8 characters long</strong></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Create Account</button>
    <button class="btn" disabled>Create Account</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```